# How to fix "undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, std

I'm running VS Code on MacOS, and I'm using `clang` to compile a simple "Hello World!" program in C++. However, when I try to run my program, VS Code gives me the following error message: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:` followed by dozens of references to the `std` library. At the bottom of the terminal, it says:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
```

(a) What does this mean? and (b) how can I fix it?
HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
      cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
      return 0;
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
      "tasks": [
            {
                  "type": "cppbuild",
                  "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
                  "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
                  "args": [
                        "-g",
                        "${file}",
                        "-o",
                        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                  ],
                  "options": {
                        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                  },
                  "problemMatcher": [
                        "$gcc"
                  ],
                  "group": {
                        "kind": "build",
                        "isDefault": true
                  },
                  "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
            }
      ],
      "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
            {
                  "name": "clang - Build and debug active file",
                  "type": "cppdbg",
                  "request": "launch",
                  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld.cpp",
                  "args": [],
                  "stopAtEntry": false,
                  "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                  "environment": [],
                  "externalConsole": false,
                  "MIMode": "lldb",
                  "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
            }
      ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your build for active file is failed. Check out your integral terminal for actual details.

Comment: Were you focus on the cpp you want to build when compile?

Comment: Show errors, would help

Comment: @LouisGo @Lala5th The terminal shows `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:` and then provides a lot of references from the `std` namespace. I assume it's something about how I gave VS Code the include path for `iostream.h`?

Comment: [Edit] your question and provide your helloworld.cpp and error messages. You don't need to include all std undefined reference error, but others has meaningful details.. It should help.

Comment: Your linker can't find the proper libraries, for `arm64`. I am assuming that you are doing this on a newer Apple machine (with an ARM processor, right?). Unfortunately I have no experience with this, but from what I read: Try `clang++`. Also a note: Do not use `using namespace std;` it looks good, but once a problem arises from it you will want to die, while debugging.

Comment: I realise now that I didn't explain it pretty well. `clang` at default links against the `c` libraries, where `std` and `iostream`, aren't really things, while `clang++` automatically links against `c++` standard libraries afaik.

Comment: @Lala5th I've switched to `clang++` now, but now I'm given the error: `'HelloWorld.cpp' doesn't contain any 'host' platform architectures: x86_64, i386, x86_64`.

Comment: @ZoltanZarlow I think your issue might be that you try to run/debug `HelloWorld.cpp`, rather than `HelloWorld` (i.e. the compiled program). Try changing `launch.json` so it contains `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld"`, without the `.cpp`

Comment: @Lala5th Apologies for the late reply. I changed the `launch.json`, but now I receive the error: `Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
The program 'HelloWorld' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).`

Comment: @ZoltanZarlow Hey. I am not familiar with VSCode that much, and from my googling it seems a MacOs specific problem. There is a fix detailed here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5079. Add `{
  "label": "Open Terminal",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"\ndo script \"echo hello\"\nend tell'",
  "problemMatcher": []
}
` to `tasks.json`, and run this specific task by `Ctrl + Shift + p` and typing `Tasks: Run Tasks` and then `Launch Terminal`. As far as they say, you only need this once, and then it works

Comment: @Lala5th This doesn't seem to work: when I run the code, it opens up in the Terminal application but stalls. I can actually run the program by typing `./HelloWorld` into the terminal, however. I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble getting VSCode to run such a simple command.

Comment: @ZoltanZarlow Yeah, from what I read it's a bug with VSCode, specifically on macOS. From what I understand some, system permission request doesn't get forwarded, and that's why it crashes. Generally you can't access memory of an other program (something a debugger needs to do), so you need to ask the kernel, but it may refuse you, and that seems to be what's happening

Comment: Thanks @Lala5th for your help. This bug is a bit frustrating, but the fact that I can manage typing in commands to the terminal for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this kind of error, Ideally you will want to link all your file with this command, NB: This is when you are using mac m1

Run this command on your terminal, replace all the files that is that directory. Compile multiple source files and link them for arm64 architecture

for example:

```
  g++ -arch arm64 -o output_file main.cpp student.cpp other_file.cpp - 
    I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib -lrequired_lib

  eg: g++ -arch arm64 -o output_file main.cc student.cc student.h
```

Then ./output_file

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple CPP files in the project then you need to add **"${fileDirname}/*.cpp"**

**tasks.json**

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
        // "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you're having a vector; error from vscode also add the c_cpp_properties.json file in .vscode directory :

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
        ],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}